# Keep browser open after executing function in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, selenium-chromedriver

I want to create a function that opens the browser, just to have it in a more compact way every time I need to call it, using Selenium Python.
This the code:

```
def prepare_website():

   chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
   driver = Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver))
   driver.maximize_window()

   driver.get(some_link)

prepare_website()
```

The problem is that after executing it closes the browser. How to keep it open instead, as it actually would do if it were not in a function?

Answer (score 1):

@Luca Giovanni Voglino, you can try the following modified code. basically `detach` option will close the driver but keep the browser open:

```
def prepare_website():
   chrome_options = Options()
   chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
   chrome_driver = ChromeDriverManager().install()
   driver = Chrome(options=chrome_options, service=Service(chrome_driver))
   driver.maximize_window()

   driver.get("http://www.google.com")

prepare_website()
```

you will need to add the following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I' ve anyway found that it does the job just by letting the function return driver and all the variables you will need for the rest of the code. Anyhow don't know if it' s the best solution, but it is sufficient to return driver to keep the browser open.